# Dialogue Like Activity is not Finishing on touch outside

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes

I created a activity looks like dialog .This what i did to achieve

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
params.height = (display.getHeight()*3)/4;
params.width = (display.getWidth()) / 2;
params.alpha = 1.0f;
params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
params.gravity=Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;;

getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 
setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new      
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,       
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 lp.setMargins(0, getIntent().getExtras().getInt("height"), 0, 0);
 layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Style I used to create this

```
  <style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

And this is what i obtained:
            [image]
The blue area is an activity .Actually wen i touch out side the activity my activity must gone from view. It's working .But activity is not getting finished .I want to finish it when i touch it

I tried `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);` and

```
@Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // If we've received a touch notification that the user has touched
    // outside the app, finish the activity.
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
      finish();
      return true;
    }

    // Delegate everything else to Activity.
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

i know this line `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>` helps to close the activity from view .but  is there any way to access this attribute programmatically .
But didn't help me .can anybody tell me how can i achieve it??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
finish();
}
```